# Output is too large to be completely displayed

Tags: r

I am currently doing a CFA and I have such a large output that the console does not show it completely. In essence, this means that I cant scroll up anymore, see only part of the output. I worked with `options(max.print=1000000)`.

Does not solve the problem.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you need to adjust the number here:

[image: RStudio settings]

Comment: Thanks! However, this does not solve it! Any other idea?

Comment: use `sink` to make a file that is used as dumping for terminal output.

Comment: There is this `rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("console_max_lines", 300)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the output into a file and check the output separately.

In C++, we do. something like this:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

Comment: While your first sentence is a decent idea here, I doubt a few lines of C++ code will be helpful to the majority of R users. (Trying to save you from upcoming downvotes).